# Can't detect click in parent element from child

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to create a table where when you click a row a dropdown shows up. I am able to detect the click fine. However, I want to be able to click anywhere else on the screen to go back to the non-editable version.

The problem is that when I use @onfocusous, it only works if I click in the row but outside of the dropdown. I want to be able to click anywhere on the page that is not the dropdown to switch back.

Here is the HTML I have.

```
<td class="@(isDropdown == true ? "hide" : "")" @onclick="BeginEdit">
    This is a test
</td>
<td class="@(isDropdown == true ? "" : "hide")" 
@onfocusout="StopEdit" id="dropdown" @onfocusout="StopEdit">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
        <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="search.blah"
                            @bind-Value="@variable"
                            EnableDropDown="true"
                            Debounce="500">
            <SelectedTemplate Context="ctx">
                 @ctx
            </SelectedTemplate>
            <ResultTemplate Context="ctx">
                @ctx
            </ResultTemplate>
        </BlazoredTypeahead>
     </div>
</td>
```

I'm guessing I need javascript to do this, but I have never used javascript or know how to use interop, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the td element lose its focus, you need first to set it focused. This is attained by setting the tabindex attribute to "0";

Try this code:

```
<td class="@(isDropdown == true ? "" : "hide")" 
@onfocusout="StopEdit" id="dropdown"  tabindex="0">
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: That makes it act a lot closer to what I was expecting. The only issue now is that you have to click in the drop downs input box for it to lose focus when you click away. I think this should do for now though.Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't have to click in the drop downs, you can click anywhere on the document.